# What is the word for "troll"?

Tags: перевод

There may be two forms of the word, the mythical creature and the Internet "troll" who spreads anger and discord through anonymous online forums.  I am interested in the second form of the word, though the first form might be interesting, too.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This word is borrowed directly from English and it's actually "тролль" or "троль" (pronounced almost like English `trol` but l is softer). It's quite common word in Internet slang and there is also a verb derived from it - `троллить`.

Also, `жирный тролль` (zh**i**rnyj trol`, literally a fat troll) - about somebody who is, well, let's put it this way, a dedicated, passionate troll.

As of palatalization (the way final "l" is pronounced softer) it's not easy to pronounce for someone who is a native speaker of a language where there's no such thing. But you can try to pronounce `trollee` and than try to pronounce `ee` very quickly, as quickly as possible. And then even shorter :)

A sidenote - "original" troll is also `тролль` in Russian (since its a Scandinavian word both in Russian and English) but actually there's a theory that English trolling was initially based on the concept of trolling - a fishing technique, and only later this word became associated with mythological creature. [More](http://www.thomasvan.com/random-philosophy/internet-slang-where-did-the-word-troll-come-from) about it.

Comment: fat troll is not necessarily a passionate and dedicated troll. fat implies that the troll is willing to use even the most crude and obvious ways of trolling, sometimes all the way down to direct swearing/name calling/etc. in contrast, "тонкий" (literally—"thin") troll tries to make the act of trolling implicit and smart, often to avoid being detected as a troll but still deliver hard feelings to the target of trolling. Usually experienced trolls can do it in both ways, but doing it "thin" requires more experience and cleverness.

Comment: @SargeBorsch good point

Comment: I think the pronouncation of the `л` with and without the "мягкий знак" can *roughly* be explained as follows: Without the `ь`, an `л` is pronounced with the "base vocal" `o`: Like pronouncing an `o`, but with the tounge touching the palate. With the `ь`, an `л` is pronounced with the "base vocal" `ee`: Like an `ee`, but with the tounge touching the palate. (I'm not a native russian speaker, so if this is entirely wrong, drop me a note, and I'll delete this comment)

Comment: @Marco13 no worries, as in my opinion, this is a very helpful explanation.

Comment: Will an average speaker understand if I use троллить in a sentence or потроллить?

Comment: @VCH250 it depends on the social group but it's same to assume that people in 20-mid 40s know it pretty well.